# “$” is not defined in angular 4 through angular-cli

Tags: angular, cross-browser, angular-cli, microsoft-edge

Project is working fine in chrome/firefox,while in EDGE\IE10,console log

```
ERROR ReferenceError: “$” is not defined
```

index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/es5-shim/4.5.10/es5-shim.js"></script>
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jquery"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

polyfills.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

app.component.ts. declare var $: any;

ie console log

[image: e]

Comment: Can you reproduce your error on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q95bz1 ?